# Why does expo give me this sqlite error when db is a function?

Tags: javascript, sqlite, expo

I keep on getting the "db.default is not an function" the file db.js is just making a table and columns in the database. When I don't call the init() function it works.

The db file:

```
import * as SQLite from 'expo-sqlite';

const db2 = SQLite.openDatabase('investments.db')

export function init () {
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db2.transaction((tx) => {
            tx.executeSql(
                'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Stuff (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, symbol TEXT NOT NULL, numbers TEXT NOT NULL, names TEXT NOT NULL );',
                [],
                () => {
                    resolve();
                },
                (_, err) => {
                 reject(err)
                }
            );
        });
    });
    return promise;
}
```

The app.js file:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import init from './helpers/db'

init().then(() => {
  console.log('db initalized')
})

export default function App() {

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: I don't see `db.default`

Comment: I think you want to `import { init } from './helpers/db'` - note the curly braces. Look up the difference between default and named exports.